# Image.Analyzer gives out unclear picture from camera on certain devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin

While using the `analyze()` function in `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` class to retrieve a picture and operate on it (do something with it), I am encountering different behavior on different Android devices. The same code, when run on a solid Samsung device returns a regular picture that I can use. But when run on a lower-end android device, it does not.

The analyze code:

```
    private class NAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

        @Override
        public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
            time = System.nanoTime();

            ImageProxy.PlaneProxy[] planes = image.getPlanes();

            ByteBuffer yBuffer = planes[0].getBuffer(); //Y
            ByteBuffer uBuffer = planes[1].getBuffer(); //U
            ByteBuffer vBuffer = planes[2].getBuffer(); //V

            int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
            int uSize = uBuffer.remaining();
            int vSize = vBuffer.remaining();

            byte[] nv21 = new byte[(ySize + uSize + vSize)];

            yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize);
            vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize);
            uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize);

            YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0, yuvImage.getWidth(), yuvImage.getHeight()), 100, stream);

            byte[] imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();
            
            //raw = data container
            raw = imageBytes;
            
            //nRunnable - operates the picture
            nRunnable.run();
            image.close();
        }
    }
```

[The low-end picture can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8pFR.jpg)

I assume that this is a hardware issue, but if anyone knows otherwise I would appreciate the help.

Comment: 1) Which low end devices  2) What is their [Performance class](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/performance-class) 3) What is the [Operating Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze#operating-modes)

Comment: @MorrisonChang
1) Unknown Chinese manufacturer, phone is from the 120$ price range
2) Could not retrieve it, phone has Android 10 on it...
3) Operating mode is: `ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST`

Comment: @MorrisonChang
Just tested this out on a Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 Pro (high-end device) and the same thing happened, same type of images occured. I am going to try and test different YUV formats, I was using only Nv21 until now.

Comment: Does anyone has answer on this? I am facing exactly same situation. it was working until now but suddenly stopped working on device and emulator too. after couple of rebuilds emulator started working again but android device gives same output as for OP. I own Xiaomi mi A2 Lite